# How to get file name while downloading a file in Java?

Tags: java, http

I have FileDownloader class that downloads the file from google drive and than these files can be used by other classes. I need also to extract filename somehow. The problem is that this solution below works good for direct links, but it doesn't work when links are shorten with bit.ly for example...
Could you please advise how I can change the code to get the right file name?

```
public class FileDownloader {

private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;


public static void downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir)
        throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(fileURL);
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

    // checking HTTP response code first
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String fileName = "";
        String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
        String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
        int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

        if (disposition != null) {
            // extracts file name from header field
            int index = disposition.indexOf("filename*=UTF-8''");

            if (index > 0) {
                fileName = disposition.substring(index + 17,
                        disposition.length());
            }
        } else {
            // extracts file name from URL
            fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                    fileURL.length());
        }

        System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
        System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
        System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
        System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

        // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
        InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

        // opens an output stream to save into file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("File downloaded");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " +  responseCode);
    }
    httpConn.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Try to inspect the response headers...

Comment: Try to be more specific as to where the error is occurring. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Are there any alternative solution how to get the file name of the file you're downloading?

Comment: When I use shorten link my FileDownloader class thinks that there's no file to download at all. But when I paste the same link to a browser to check downloading of the file starts immediately

Answer (score -1):

Alternate Code to get File details from any HTTP URL using Java API:

URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/somepath/filename.extension");

```
    System.out.println(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(url.getPath()));
```

//  filename

```
    System.out.println(FilenameUtils.getName(url.getPath()));
```

// filename.extension

Comment: Thanks. I will try. Please, tell me this works also with indirect links (because I see "filname.extension" in your description)?